# Delete all the data from all tables

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, delete

I have a little problem. I have to delete all the data from our database. I don't want to drop tables, only delete the data sets.

These are 47 tables in total.

I tried the following:

```
Delete FROM(select TABLE_NAME from USER_TABLES);
Delete FROM(select * from ALL_ALL_TABLES Where OWNER = 'DB_NAME')
```

But that is not valid. How can I efficiently remove all the data from all my tables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generate the statements you need

```
select 'DELETE FROM '||table_name||' ;' from user_tables;
```

Even better would be using `TRUNCATE` instead of `DELETE`.  That would prevent generating extra redo vectors in the redo log - in the end all you want to do is just get rid of the data. It would also avoid all actions by any `DELETE` triggers that the tables have.

```
select 'TRUNCATE TABLE '||table_name||' ;' from user_tables;
```

Comment: Or better `TRUNCATE` instead of `DELETE FROM` – there's really no need to generate extra redo vectors in the redo log if all you want to do is just get rid of the data.

Answer (score -6):

You should use TRUNCATE instead of DELETE if you is using SQL Server. Because it will reduce log records in log file.

```
USE <your database>;
GO

DECLARE @table_name varchar(100);

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE type='U' 
OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @table_name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
BEGIN
    EXEC (N'TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.'+@table_name);
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @table_name
END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

Comment: The question obviously has "oracle" tag.

Answer (score -6):

`TRUNCATE TABLE_NAME;`
 does the magic for you.

Comment: Question was to delete from all tables without having to write out each of the 47 `TRUNCATE` commands